# Send emails in background from WSGI Bottle App

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle, apscheduler

I have a REST API using the bottle.py framework in apache using mod_wsgi. I need to send out emails when certain actions occur but that process is slowing down the server API response, often to the point of timeout.

I've looked into things like APScheduler but all the examples are for Flask and I'm too deep into using Bottle to switch at the moment, so that's not an option.

Is there a good way without doing cron jobs and such to send emails on a background task via bottle.py?

Comment: Do you need to guarantee that the emails are sent? If you do, you need to use a system with a persistent task queue such as Celery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending out emails while the request is waiting on the other end of the line, couldn't you just queue up the emails for future processing?

Then you'd have a separate thread that reads from the email queue and does the sending.

---

Alternatively, you could use an [asynchronous server](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#switching-the-server-backend) (like gevent) and spawn email tasks which would be processed independently, after you've finished responding to each HTTP request.